# VSCode not emulating other file than my old version of index

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Faced with the prospects of having to code, in order to build a digital annex for my thesis, I've wrote a bunch of very raw lines: a index with some imagelinks - it's a catalogue of sculptures. Each sculpture have it's own standard page, called n0, designed to be a "paper" form ready to be filled with info.

A friend of mine improved my original n0 - but when I try to emulate it via VSCode, software shows only my main index page. Why is that? I mean, I didn't even tried to open the index! I've looked around if someone had the same basic issue, but fact is, noob as I am, I dunno what exactly to search for or which words to use... So, I don't understand if these ppl had the same issue as I'm having.

Comment: What happens when you double click the html file in the file explorer? Does that open it?

Comment: It opens directly in my browser with the modifications that were made - is a Chrome icon, after all. Same thing in Firefox.

Comment: I think I solved it! Just replaced the old n0 file in the folder where the index was with the new one. Now, when I emulate it, it shows the new n0 coding. Still didn't understand why it showed my index before, though.

Comment: You probably didn’t save the file :-D make sure to do curl+s very often

Comment: I meant ctrl/cmd+s haha

Comment: Hahaha nooo, I had two versions of the same file in different folders. Just replaced the old one, which is in the same folder as index, with the new one, and voilá! Ty for answering Beast!

Comment: Okay, sounds good haha :-D